# Are there incongruent pythagorean triangles with the same perimeter and same area?

Tags: geometry

I found there are two incongruent isosceles triangles with integer sides and areas, where both have same perimeter, same area.

I looked around Dickson's History of Number Theory but couldn't find where the right triangle version is treated. [I thought if a nonexistence proof was simple it would pop up in my search, but found none.]

It may be simple to show none exist, but I had no luck, only filled  few notebook pages with formulas going nowhere. Reference/example/proof appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider two right triangles, with hypotenuses $p$ and $q$ and respective acute angles $\theta$ and $\phi$. To see that having equal perimeter and area makes them congruent, it suffices to show that 
$$\theta = \phi \qquad\text{or}\qquad \theta+\phi=\frac{\pi}{2} \tag{0}$$
(Either makes the triangles similar, which in turn makes them congruent.)

Equating perimeters and areas gives a system we can write as

$$\begin{align}
p(1+\sin\theta+\cos\theta) &= q(1+\sin\phi+\cos\phi) \\
p^2 \sin\theta \cos\theta &= q^2 \sin\phi \cos\phi
\end{align} \tag{1}$$

Defining $u:=\tan(\theta/2)$, [we "know"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution) that
$$\sin\theta = \frac{2u}{1+u^2} \qquad \cos\theta=\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2} \quad\to\quad 1+\cos\theta+\sin\theta= \frac{2 (1 + u)}{1 + u^2}$$
and likewise for $v:=\tan(\phi/2)$. Thus, $(1)$ can be rewritten as
$$\begin{align}
p\frac{(1+u)}{1+u^2} &= q\frac{(1+v)}{1+v^2} \\[4pt]
p^2\frac{u(1+u)(1-u)}{(1+u^2)^2} &= q^2\frac{v(1+v)(1-v)}{(1+v^2)^2}
\end{align}\tag{2}$$
Dividing the second equation by the square of the first ...

$$\frac{u(1-u)}{1+u} = \frac{v(1-v)}{1+v} \quad\to\quad (u-v)(uv+u+v-1)=0 \quad\to\quad u=v, \text{ or } \frac{u+v}{1-uv}=1 \tag{3}$$

Therefore, we have one of the following situations (bearing in mind that $\theta/2$ and $\phi/2$ are each at most $\pi/4$, so that we may draw appropriate conclusions from these tangent inequalities):
$$\begin{align}
\tan\frac{\theta}{2}=\tan\frac{\phi}{2} &\quad\to\quad \theta=\phi \\[4pt]
\frac{\tan(\theta/2)+\tan(\phi/2)}{1-\tan(\theta/2)\tan(\phi/2)} = 1 &\quad\to\quad
\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}+\frac{\phi}{2}\right)=\tan\frac{\pi}{4} \quad\to\quad \theta+\phi=\frac{\pi}{2}\end{align} \tag{4}$$
which match the sufficient conditions in $(0)$. $\square$

Answer (score 9):

Let $S$ be the circumference and $A$ twice the area of a triangle.

Then, 
$$a_i+b_i+\sqrt{a_i^2+b_i^2}=S
 \text{ and } a_ib_i=A. \tag{1}$$ 
After squaring, $S^2+2A-2S(a_i+b_i)=0$ and from here $a_i+b_i=S/2+A/S$. Thus, $c_i=S-(a_i+b_i)=S/2-A/S=c$, that is,  triangles have the same hypotenuse.

Then, $a_i+b_i=S-c=T$ and $a_ib_i=A$, which results in a solutions for $a_i$ and $b_i$ expressed in terms of constants $A$ and $T$. Although one of the resulting equations is quadratic, there is a symmetric pair of solutions (thank you for comments below). Hence, all sides must be the same.

Comment: Really nice proof. I have a niggle with your last statement though. In general, $2$ equations with $2$ unknowns may well have multiple solutions if they are not linear. For example, the OP mentions isosceles triangles, where the triangles $(8,8,12)$ and $(6,11,11)$ have the same perimeter and area even though isosceles triangles are also parametrised by two variables. Of course, in your case you know the sum and product of $a$ and $b$, which is a particularly nice pair of equations well known to have a symmetric pair of solutions.

Comment: @Jaap Scherphuis -- Thank you for your comment and clarification.

Comment: @Dawood ibn Kareem -- Thanks for the comment. I added in the answer the clarification made by Jaap Scherphuis.

Answer (score 7):

The area and the perimeter uniquely define the radius of the inscribed circle because $A=\frac12Pr$, and the hypotenuse because $r=\frac{P}{2}-c$. That fixes both $a+b=P-c$ and $ab=2A$ so $a$ and $b$ are also unique up to permutation, QED.

Answer (score 6):

Consider a right-angled triangle with sides $a$ and $b$.
The hypotenuse has length $c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.
Its area is $ab/2$, and perimeter is $a+b+c$.

I will allow $a,b,c$ to be any positive real numbers, not restrict them to positive integers.

Suppose we scale the triangles such that $ab=1$, (i.e. an area of $1/2$). Is it possible to have two of these triangles that are distinct but with the same perimeter?

We may assume that $a$ is the longer side, i.e. $a>b$, so we must have $a>1$.

The perimeter is
$$P(a) = a+b+c\\ = a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\\ = a+\frac{1}{a}+\sqrt{a^2+\frac{1}{a^2}}$$

This is an increasing function on the interval $[1,\infty)$ because its derivative w.r.t. $a$ is positive for $a>1$. This is tedious to check by hand, so I used [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%20x%2B1%2Fx%2Bsqrt(x%5E2%2B1%2Fx%5E2)). You can however understand why this is the case by noticing that if you increase $a$, then the rate at which $a$ increases is larger than the rate at which $1/a$ decreases, and the same holds for $a^2$ versus $1/a^2$.

This means that there are no two values of $a$, both with $a>1$ for which you get the same perimeter.

Bringing it back to the original problem, it means that there are no two right-angled triangles with the same perimeter and area, unless they have the same sides. Basically, given an area and a perimeter, their two equations uniquely determine the two triangle sides because the lines those equations represent are not curved enough to intersect multiple times.

---

P.S. By the way, the OP mentioned that there are pairs of isosceles triangles with matching areas and perimeters, even when all sides and the area are integers. Two examples are:
$(29,29,40)$ and $(37,37,24)$,
and also
$(218,218,240)$ and $(233,233,210)$.

Comment: How to scale the 3,4,5 triangle so its area is 1/2? [i.e.$ab=1$ in notation you use.] By "scale" do you mean multiply all sides by some factor $k$ ?

Comment: Yes. Since in this case $ab=12$ you'd divide both sides by $\sqrt{12}$, so that corresponds to $a=3/\sqrt{12}=\sqrt{3}/2$ and $b=4/\sqrt{12}=2\sqrt{3}/3$.

Answer (score 2):

Long Comment:

You can at least give the simple formulae for the perimeter $P$ and area $A$ of a right angle triangle.

If $z^2=x^2+y^2$ is a primitive Pythagorean triangle with $x$ being the base of the triangle and $y$ being the height (due to the right angle), then $P=x+y+z$ and $A=\frac{1}{2}xy$

Then you can quote the formulae for primitive Pythagorean Triples, where $z=\left(a^2+b^2\right)$, $x=\left(a^2-b^2\right)$ and $y=2ab$

To expand to all the non primitive Pythagorean triangles we have

$$(cz)^2=(cx)^2+(cy)^2$$

Therefore

$$P=a(2a+2b)c$$
$$A=\frac{1}{2} \left(a^2-b^2\right)(2ab)c^2=\left(a^2-b^2\right)abc^2$$

For two incongruent Pythagorean triangles 1 and 2 the condition is

$$P_1=P_2 \;\;\text{and} \;\; A_1=A_2$$

For Perimeter:
$$a_1(2a_1+2b_1)c_1=a_2(2a_2+2b_2)c_2$$
$$\frac{a_2+b_2}{a_1+b_1}=\frac{a_1c_1}{a_2c_2}\tag{1}$$
For Area:
$$\left(a_1^2-b_1^2\right)a_1b_1c_1^2=\left(a_2^2-b_2^2\right)a_2b_2c_2^2$$
$$\frac{a_2+b_2}{a_1+b_1}=\frac{a_1c_1}{a_2c_2}\left(\frac{b_1c_1}{b_2c_2}\frac{ (a_1-b_1) }{ (a_2-b_2) } \right)$$

Therefore combining both gives

$$b_1c_1(a_1-b_1)=b_2c_2(a_2-b_2)\tag{2}$$

Update:

Using (1) and (2) we can eliminate the variables $c_1$ and $c_2$ eventually giving
$$\frac{ (a_2+b_2) a_2 }{ (a_1+b_1) a_1 }=\frac{ (a_2-b_2) b_2 }{ (a_1-b_1) b_1 }$$
or
$$\frac{ (a_2+b_2) a_2 }{ (a_2-b_2) b_2 }=\frac{ (a_1+b_1) a_1 }{ (a_1-b_1) b_1 }$$

Comment: In the version you use for primitive triples I think one needs $a,b$ odd and coprime, $a>b$ to give triples of positives. [That seems it would be known in that version…] I used the other version in my attempt, $p^2-q^2,2pq,p^2+q^2$ with $p,q$ coprime opposite parity and $p>q.$ Still didn't go to a finish in my attempts though.

Comment: updated to your version

Answer (score 0):

This a Pythagorean triple treatment of area to perimeter ratios.

We can find Pythagorean triples, if they exist, for any ratio $R$ of area/perimeter by finding the $m,n$(s) that represent them using the following formula which includes a difined finite search for values of $m$. Whenever the $m$ $R$ combination yields a positive integer for $n$, we have the $m,n$ for a triple.
We begin by solving the area/perimeter equation for $n$ where area=$D$ so as not to confuse it with $A,B,C$.

$$D=\frac{AB}{2}=\frac{(m^2-n^2)*2mn}{2}=mn(m^2-n^2)\quad P=(m^2-n^2)+2mn+(m^2+n^2)=2m^2+2mn$$

$$\frac{D}{P}=\frac{mn(m^2-n^2)}{2m^2+2mn}=\frac{mn(m-n)(m+n)}{2m(m+n)}=\frac{n(m-n)}{2}=R\qquad n^2-mn+2R=0$$

$$n=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=\frac{m\pm\sqrt{m^2-4*1*2R}}{2*1}$$

$$n=\frac{m\pm \sqrt{m^2-8R}}{2}\text{ where }\lceil\sqrt{8R}\space \rceil \le m \le 2R+1$$

Example: For $R=0.5\quad \sqrt{8*0.5}=2\le m \le 2*0.5+1=2$

$$n=\frac{2\pm \sqrt{2^2-8*0.5}}{2}=1\qquad f(2,1)=(3,4,5)$$
But you are asking about $R=1$ and there only two such Pythagorean triples to be found.

$$R=1\rightarrow 3\le m \le 3\quad f(3,2)=(5,12,13)\quad f(3,1)=(8,6,10)$$
For other ratios:
$$R=1.5\rightarrow 4\le m \le 4\quad f(4,3)=(7,24,25)\quad f(4,1)=(15,8,17)$$

$$R=2\rightarrow 4\le m \le 5\quad f(4,2)=(12,16,20)\quad f(5,4)=(9,40,41)\quad f(5,1)=(24,10,26)$$

$$R=2.5\rightarrow 4\le m \le 6\quad f(6,5)=(11,60,61)\quad f(6,1)=(35,12,37)$$

$$R=3\rightarrow 4\le m \le 7\quad f(5,3)=(16,30,34)\quad f(5,2)=(21,20,29)\quad f(7,6)=(13,84,85)\quad f(7,1)=(48,14,50)$$

$$R=18\rightarrow 12\le m \le 37\quad f(12,6)=(108,144,180)\quad f(13,9)=(88,234,250)\quad f(13,4)=(153,104,185)\quad f(15,12)=(81,360,369)\quad f(15,3)=(216,90,234)\quad f(20,18)=(76,720,724)\quad f(20,2)=(396,80,404)\quad f(37,36)=(73,2664,2665)\quad f(37,1)=(1368,74,1370)$$

Aside: you can always find one primitive triple for a given $R$ if you let $(m,n)=(2R+1,2R)$.